# Align two containers holding different types by calling transform methods

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, time-complexity

I have two STL containers (currently vectors) holding different types of objects. The two types both have a method returning an identifier which can be used to "compare" the different types. The elements in both containers are not sorted and comparing two identifiers might be "expensive" (e.g. string comparisons). Both containers are expected to have similar size, with probably << 100 elements each.

I now want to do the following:

- Case 1: If container A and container B both contain elements for which the identifiers compare equal, I want to call a method on the element of container A.
- Case 2: If container B contains an element with an identifier for which no corresponding element is contained in A, I want to create such an element and insert it into A.
- Case 3: If container A contains an element with an identifier for which no corresponding element is contained in B, I want to call a method on this element and remove it from A.

So after all this it should hold

- The number of elements in both containers should are equal
- Container B was not modified
- For each element in container A there should be an element in container B for which the identifiers compare equal and vice versa

Is there an efficient way to do this? I can only think of an algorithm that would have O(2*n*m) runtime complexity what sounds too much.

```
std::vector<T1> containerA;
std::vector<T2> containerB;

for(auto &elementA : containerA)
{
  std::vector<T2>::iterator bIter = std::find_if(containerB.begin(), containerB.end(), [elementA](const T2 &elementB){ return (elementA.getId() == elementB.getId()); })
  if(bIter == containerB.end())
  {
    // case 3
    elementA.foo();
    // remove elementA from containerA
  }

  // case 1
  elementA.bar((*bIter));
}

for(const auto &elementB : containerB)
{
  std::vector<T1>::iterator aIter = std::find_if(containerA.begin(), containerA.end(), [elementB](const T1 &elementA){ return (elementA.getId() == elementB.getId()); })
  if(aIter == containerA.end())
  {
    // case 2
    T1 newElement(elementB);
    containerA.push_back(newElement);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there exists a total order on `A sum B` you can try the following:

1. Let `A'` = `sorted A`
2. Let `B'` = `sorted B`
3. For each `b` in `B'` find `a` from `A'` (since `A'` is sorted we can use binary search) such that `b = a`. If no such element exists a add new element to `A` otherwise perform operation on `(b, a)`
4. For each `a` in `A'` find `b` from `B'` (since `B'` is sorted we can use binary search) such that `a = b`. If no such element exists a mark `a` as removed in `A` otherwise perform operation on `(a, b)`
5. Remove all marked elements from `A`

Time complexity is `O(nlogn)`

Comment: I was thinking that sorting both ranges upfront might cause performance problems but maybe this falls under *premature optimization*...I will accept your answer

Comment: @sigy I really disagree with that. I think that choosing a good algorithm at the beginning is not a "premature optimization". Especially if it does not require much effort.

Comment: I agree with that! What I meant was that thinking sorting might be too slow because of string comparisons without testing if it really is a problem was *premature optimization*. The algorithm it self does not take into account how expensive the sorting is.